# Page speed, css vs if function

Tags: css, performance, if-statement

I was wondering which would be faster regarding page loading time, and the page speed in global. I have a nice situation where I appreciate any input.

Right now I got approximately 50 images which I can set up via CSS as in `background-image` in the stylesheet or a `if condition <img src....>`

Any thoughts on this matter ? :)

Comment: I dont understand, what you want to compare, what is faster? What are you trying to do?

Comment: The page loading time :)
Since the page loads the whole css style sheet, if i were to use an if page id as condition and place the images in the if, but there would be 50 if conditions. So I am trying to figure out which would load faster :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> First case: you need to load all at same time, so you need to use css

---

> Second case: you need to load dynamic(better away), example when scroll down load next line of images (there many examples), so you need to use js or jquery

Comment: Thank you and sorry for not being too clear on this, i got an ecommerce site with 50 different products, every image of those 50 is for a single product page :)

Comment: Use jquery lazy load, this will save you :D

Answer (score 3):

Using img instead of background-image can dramatically improve performance of animations over a background and faster regarding page loading time

so you should be use if condition  instead of background-image

Comment: thank you for the input :)
I am still comparing 50 css class rules and 50 if statements